# Get the minimum amount of degrees recorded in a day

Tags: pascal

I need to make a program that gets the minimum amount of degrees recorded in a day at what hour, I made the program, I am getting the correct hour at which the min amount of degrees were recorded but I am not getting the correct amount of degrees

```
Program P1;

Type 
    Hour = 0..23;
    Degrees = -40..40;
    Temperature = array [Hour] of Degrees;

var 
    t : Temperature;
    i, min_t, max_t, hour_t_min, hour_t_max : integer;

    procedure test;
    begin
        for i := 0 to 23 do
        begin
            writeln('Enter the temperature at hour ', i);
            readln(t[i]);
            min_t := t[0];
         
            if min_t > t[i] then 
            begin 
                min_t := t[i]; 
                ora_t_min := i; 
            end;

            if max_t < t[i] then 
            begin 
                max_t := t[i]; 
                ora_t_max := i; 
            end;
        end;
    
        writeln('temp min ', min_t, ' at hour ', hour_t_min);
        writeln('temp max ', max_t, ' at hour ', hour_t_max);
    end; {procedure}

begin { main }
    test;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Min_t (and max_t) should be initialized outside and before the loop.
You are assigning min_t:=t[0] in each loop, this is wrong, and max_t is not being initialized. Also, I think this is a typo, ora_t_min and ora_t_max should be changed to hour_t_min and hour_t_max:

Something like this:

```
min_t := 40;
max_t := -40;
for i := 0 to 23 do
    begin
        writeln('Enter the temperature at hour ', i);
        readln(t[i]);
        if min_t > t[i] then begin min_t := t[i]; hour_t_min := i; end;
        if max_t < t[i] then begin max_t := t[i]; hour_t_max := i; end;
    end;
    writeln('temp min ', min_t, ' at hour ', hour_t_min);
    writeln('temp max ', max_t, ' at hour ', hour_t_max);
end;
```